Using ST-C530 with front derailleur instead of intego 3 speed hub
Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use a Shimano Nexave ST-C530 shifter with a FD-M530 front derailleur and if so how to properly connect it?  I'm using a FH-M510 rear hub instead of a 3 speed hub.  Is there anyway to make it work?

how to make it work: remove the click box from the end, attach the shifter cable to the derailleur. I have no idea if the pull ratio of the shifter matches the needs of your front derailleur though.
